In d3 multiline chart with focus and context, how do I restrict brushing of context to specific dates?
I have a multiline chart created with d3.js using focus and context, where I can use the context to brush to a different extent of dates. My data only includes dates that are the first of each month, but when brushing, one can brush between the dates. I want the brush to snap to the discrete dates in my data because eventually I want to output the selected data in a table.
I found this example, based on this stackoverflow question, that uses d3v3, but I'm having a hard time translating it to my needs. Any help would be very welcome.


let timeW = 960,
    timeH = 500

  let timeMargin = { top: 20, right: 250, bottom: 130, left: 60 },
    timeMargin2 = { top: 410, right: 250, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
    timeWidth = timeW - timeMargin.left - timeMargin.right,
    timeHeight = timeH - timeMargin.top - timeMargin.bottom,
    timeHeight2 = timeH - timeMargin2.top - timeMargin2.bottom;

  var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

  let timeseries = d3.select("#timeseries-container").append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'timeseries')
    .attr("width", timeWidth + timeMargin.left + timeMargin.right)
    .attr("height", timeHeight + timeMargin.top + timeMargin.bottom)

  var graph = timeseries.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + timeMargin.left + ',' + timeMargin.top + ')');

  var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, timeWidth]),
    x3 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, timeWidth]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([timeHeight, 0]),
    y3 = d3.scaleLinear().range([timeHeight2, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x3),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y2);

  var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [timeWidth, timeHeight2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [timeWidth, timeHeight]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [timeWidth, timeHeight]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x2(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y2(d.value); });

  var line2 = d3.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x3(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y3(d.value); });

  timeseries.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", timeWidth)
    .attr("height", timeHeight);

  var focus = timeseries.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + timeMargin.left + "," + timeMargin.top + ")");

  var context = timeseries.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + timeMargin2.left + "," + timeMargin2.top + ")");

  d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprucegoose1/sample-data/main/sample.csv").then(function (data) {

    data.forEach((d) => {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.value = +d.value;
    })

    x2.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
    y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
    x3.domain(x2.domain());
    y3.domain(y2.domain());

    const dataNest = d3.group(data, d => d.state)

    const seriesColors = ["#003F5C", "#38CFE8"]

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .range(seriesColors);

    focus
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(dataNest)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr('class', 'groups')
      .attr("d", d => {
        d.line = this;
        return line(d[1]);
      })
      .style("stroke", d => color(d[0]))
      .style("stroke-width", 1)
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

    focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + timeHeight + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

    context
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(dataNest)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr('class', 'groups')
      .attr("d", d => {
        d.line = this;
        return line2(d[1]);
      })
      .style("stroke", d => color(d[0]))
      .style("stroke-width", 1)
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

    context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + timeHeight2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x2.range());

  });

  let zoombrush;
  function brushed(event) {
    var s = event.selection || x2.range();
    if (s[1] === s[0]) s[1] += .5;

    if (event.mode === "move") {
      var extentlength = Math.round(s[1] - s[0])
      event.target.extent([Math.round(s[0] + 0.5) - 0.5,
      Math.round(s[0] + 0.5) - 0.5 + extentlength])
    } else {
      event.target.extent([Math.round(s[0] + 0.5) - 0.5,
      Math.round(s[1] + 0.5) - 0.5])
    }
    event.target(d3.select(this))

    x2.domain(s.map(x3.invert, x3));
    focus.selectAll(".groups")
      .attr("d", d => {
        d.line = this;
        return line(d[1]);
      })

    focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
    timeseries.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(timeWidth / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
    zoombrush = 0;
  }
  brush.on('end', (event, d) => {
  })

  function zoomed(event) {
    if (zoombrush) return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
    zoombrush = 1;

    var t = event.transform;
    x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
    focus.select(".groups").attr("d", line);
    focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
    context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
    zoombrush = 0;
  }
.line {
    stroke: #333;
    fill: none;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
  }

  .zoom {
    cursor: move;
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .handle {
    fill: #4D4E56;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
    stroke-width: 1.25px;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="timeseries-container"></div>




Have you seen this example?

I hadn't seen that.

Here is an example using d3 v7.  I removed the zoom behavior completely.  It was an over-complicated way just to re-draw the lines.


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .line {
        stroke: #333;
        fill: none;
        clip-path: url(#clip);
      }

      .handle {
        fill: #4d4e56;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-opacity: 0.5;
        stroke-width: 1.25px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="timeseries-container"></div>

    <script>
      let timeW = 960,
        timeH = 500;

      let timeMargin = { top: 20, right: 250, bottom: 130, left: 60 },
        timeMargin2 = { top: 410, right: 250, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
        timeWidth = timeW - timeMargin.left - timeMargin.right,
        timeHeight = timeH - timeMargin.top - timeMargin.bottom,
        timeHeight2 = timeH - timeMargin2.top - timeMargin2.bottom;

      var parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');

      let timeseries = d3
        .select('#timeseries-container')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('id', 'timeseries')
        .attr('width', timeWidth + timeMargin.left + timeMargin.right)
        .attr('height', timeHeight + timeMargin.top + timeMargin.bottom);

      var graph = timeseries
        .append('g')
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' + timeMargin.left + ',' + timeMargin.top + ')'
        );

      var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, timeWidth]),
        x3 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, timeWidth]),
        y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([timeHeight, 0]),
        y3 = d3.scaleLinear().range([timeHeight2, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x2),
        xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x3),
        yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y2);

      var brush = d3
        .brushX()
        .extent([
          [0, 0],
          [timeWidth, timeHeight2],
        ])
        .on('brush', brush)
        .on('end', brushed);

      var line = d3
        .line()
        .x(function (d) {
          return x2(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
          return y2(d.value);
        });

      var line2 = d3
        .line()
        .x(function (d) {
          return x3(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
          return y3(d.value);
        });

      timeseries.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", timeWidth)
        .attr("height", timeHeight);

      var focus = timeseries
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'focus')
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' + timeMargin.left + ',' + timeMargin.top + ')'
        );

      var context = timeseries
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'context')
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' + timeMargin2.left + ',' + timeMargin2.top + ')'
        );

      d3.csv(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprucegoose1/sample-data/main/sample.csv'
      ).then(function (data) {

        data.forEach((d) => {
          d.date = parseDate(d.date);
          d.value = +d.value;
        });

        x2.domain(
          d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.date;
          })
        );
        y2.domain([
          0,
          d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.value;
          }),
        ]);
        x3.domain(x2.domain());
        y3.domain(y2.domain());

        const dataNest = d3.group(data, (d) => d.state);

        const seriesColors = ['#003F5C', '#38CFE8'];

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(seriesColors);

        focus
          .selectAll('path')
          .data(dataNest)
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('class', 'focus_lines')
          .attr('d', (d) => {
            d.line = this;
            return line(d[1]);
          })
          .style('stroke', (d) => color(d[0]))
          .style('stroke-width', 1)
          .style('fill', 'none')
          .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');

        focus
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + timeHeight + ')')
          .call(xAxis);

        focus.append('g').attr('class', 'axis axis--y').call(yAxis);

        context
          .selectAll('path')
          .data(dataNest)
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('class', 'groups')
          .attr('d', (d) => {
            d.line = this;
            return line2(d[1]);
          })
          .style('stroke', (d) => color(d[0]))
          .style('stroke-width', 1)
          .style('fill', 'none')
          .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');

        context
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + timeHeight2 + ')')
          .call(xAxis2);

        context
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'brush')
          .call(brush)
          .call(brush.move, x2.range());
      });

      function brush(event) {
        if (!event.sourceEvent) return;

        const d0 = event.selection.map(x3.invert),
          start = d3.timeMonth.floor(d0[0]),
          end = d3.timeMonth.ceil(d0[1]);

        x2.domain([start, end]);
        d3.select(this).call(brush.move, [x3(start), x3(end)]);
      }

      function brushed(event){
        const lines = d3.selectAll('.focus_lines')
          .attr('d', (d) => {
            return line(d[1]);
          });

          d3.select(".axis--x").call(d3.axisBottom(x2))
      };
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



